# get continuosly increasing sale records from table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables

```
Product
  ProdId, ProdName
    1     A
    2     B
```

and

```
Sale
SaleId, ProdId, Sale, Year
1,      1,      100,  2012
2,      1,      130,  2013
3,      2,      100,  2012,
4,      1,      150,  2014,
5,      1,      180,  2015
6,      2,      120,  2013,
7,      2,       90,  2014,
8,      2,      130,  2015
```

I want the name of product whose sale is continuosly increasing.
Like Product "A" has sale record like in year 2012 - 100 Units,2013 - 130 Units,2014 - 150 Units,2015 - 180 Units, So this product A is having continuous increase in sale. Another case of non-continuous record is, product "B" having sale record 2012 - 100 Units,2013 - 120 Units,2014 - 90 Units, 2015 - 130 Units, So for product "B", it is not continuous.

I want records like product "A", who is having continuous increasing sale.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Find records for each product and loop through them to find differences for each year. If the difference is always positive, you have your product.

Comment: Terrible advice @VarunMehta

Comment: Do you want an average of the change in sale per year? or only to display products that have positive change every year?

Comment: May be, but it will give you the result. @scsimon

Comment: @VarunMetha Don't use a loop for this. There are set based solutions.

Comment: @VarunMehta I think he's just expecting a set based answer instead of looping anything when we're in a SQL sub.  It's very rare that a looping solution can get you a more efficient answer in SQL.

Comment: @VarunMehta you could walk to work in the Arizona sun every day too, but that doesn't mean you should do it or that it's sustainable or logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cross apply` to get the previous year's sale amount and check with conditional aggregation for the increasing amount condition.

```
select prodid 
from sale s1
cross apply (select sale as prev_sale 
             from sale s2 
             where s1.prodid=s2.prodid and s2.year=s1.year-1) s2
group by prodid
having sum(case when sale-prev_sale<0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

To get the all the rows for such prodId's, use

```
select * from sale 
where prodid in (select prodid 
                 from sale s1
                 cross apply (select sale as prev_sale 
                              from sale s2 
                              where s1.prodid=s2.prodid and s2.year=s1.year-1) s2
                 group by prodid
                 having sum(case when sale-prev_sale<0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `row_number()` twice:

```
select prod_id
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s.prod_id order by sale) as seqnum_s,
             row_number() over (partition by s.prod_id order by year) as seqnum_y
      from sales s
     ) s
group by prod_id
having sum( case when seqnum_s = seqnum_y then 1 else 0 end) = count(*);
```

That is, order by the year and the sales.  When all row numbers are the same, then the sales are increasing.

Note:  There are some cases where tied sales might be considered increasing.  This can be handled by the logic -- either by excluding or including such situations.  I have not included logic for this, because your question is not clear what to do in that situation.

Comment: Best answer IMHO. Good idea

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with a CTE

```
declare @sale table (SaleID int, ProdId int, Sale int, Year int)
insert into @sale
values
(1,1,100,2012),
(2,1,130,2013),
(3,2,100,2012),
(4,1,150,2014),
(5,1,180,2015),
(6,2,120,2013),
(7,2,90,2014),
(8,2,130,2015)

declare @product table (ProdID int, ProdName char(1))
insert into @product
values
(1,'A'),
(2,'B')

;with cte as(
select
    row_number() over (partition by ProdId order by Year) as RN
    ,*
from @sale)

select 
    p.ProdName 
    ,cte.*
from cte 
inner join
    @product p on 
    p.ProdID=cte.ProdId
where cte.ProdId IN
    (select distinct
        c1.ProdId
    from cte c1
        left join
        cte c2 on c2.RN = c1.rn+1 and c2.ProdId = c1.ProdId 
    group by c1.ProdId
    having min(case when c1.Sale < isnull(c2.Sale,999999) then 1 else 0 end) = 1)
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----------+----+--------+--------+------+------+
| ProdName | RN | SaleID | ProdId | Sale | Year |
+----------+----+--------+--------+------+------+
| A        |  1 |      1 |      1 |  100 | 2012 |
| A        |  2 |      2 |      1 |  130 | 2013 |
| A        |  3 |      4 |      1 |  150 | 2014 |
| A        |  4 |      5 |      1 |  180 | 2015 |
+----------+----+--------+--------+------+------+
```